# Temporarily disable function on submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form where the submit button triggers a function. Let's call it `myFunction()`. I need this function to be disabled for 30 seconds after submit but I need the submit button to continue to work. I do not want want to disable the entire button, just the function it triggers. (If the user hits the button again before 30 seconds I need it to submit again, but not execute `myFunction` a second time.) I've tried a million different things but to no avail. I don't even know which code to post as an example.

```
<FORM ID="myform">
    <INPUT ID="mysubmit" TYPE="SUBMIT" ONCLICK="myFunction();">
</FORM>
```

What's the easiest, simplest way to do this using JavaScript?

Comment: Well, if submitting the form reloads the page, that will be rather difficult. Can you explain the situation a little more? Maybe there's a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: No, the form action is targetted to an adjacent frame. The form and Submit button are always visible and never reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
setTimeout(myFuction, 30000) // wait for 30 seconds and then call function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<FORM ID="myform">
<INPUT ID="mysubmit" TYPE="SUBMIT" onClick="myFuction2();">
</FORM>


function myFuction() {
    ...
}

function myFuction2() {
    toggleSubmit();
    setTimeout("toggleSubmit", 30000);
    myFuction();
}

function toggleSubmit() {
    if (document.getElementById('mysubmit').onclick == null) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').onclick = myFuction2;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').onclick = null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: this is not working. gave me some ideas though. i think the best way to go about this would be to set a timestamp, or a 30 second timer, then when the button is pressed do something like if (timer > 30){myFunction()} how could this be done?